# d3 Zoomable Circle Packing in vue js

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

how can i create d.3js Zoomable Circle Packing in vue js
like this
https://bl.ocks.org/fdlk/076469462d00ba39960f854df9acda56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created an example with the chart from the link. The main thing is that you have to call D3 code in the `mounted()` life-cycle hook of the Vue instance and you also need to have the `SVG` element in your `<template>`

Example with the same chart:

```js
const jsonData = {"name":"variants","children":[{"name":"2","children":[{"name":"p23.3","children":[{"name":"IFT172","children":[{"name":"undefined","size":28},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaaq","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaaci","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaabe","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaacm","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaaca","size":8},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaace","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaab4","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaae","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaace","size":9},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaacq","size":9},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaa4","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaaau","size":13},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaay","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaaby","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaabq","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaam","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaaq","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaabi","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaae","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaacu","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaabm","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaabu","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaai","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaac4","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaabq","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaaay","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaabm","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaa4","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaau","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaabi","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaba","size":12},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaay","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaca","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaacq","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaaa4","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaabi","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaabe","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaci","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaai","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaba","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaada","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaabe","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaacm","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaaau","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3iascvqjaabaaam","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3eascvqjaabaaba","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjs3gascvqjaabaab4","size":3}]}]}]},{"name":"3","children":[{"name":"p21.31","children":[{"name":"CACNA2D2","children":[{"name":"aaaacxi7gjufoascvqjaabaafi","size":2},{"name":"undefined","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjufqascvqjaabaaae","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjufqascvqjaabaadu","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjufqascvqjaabaaee","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjufqascvqjaabaace","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjufqascvqjaabaaca","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjufqascvqjaabaad4","size":2}]},{"name":"LARS2","children":[{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaag4","size":30},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaagy","size":9},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaaga","size":16},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaagq","size":8},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaahi","size":11},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaagm","size":14},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaage","size":1},{"name":"undefined","size":10},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaaia","size":12},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaahy","size":15},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaafq","size":8},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaaha","size":10},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaagu","size":12},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaaf4","size":10},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj6pmascvqjaabaahq","size":10}]}]}]},{"name":"7","children":[{"name":"q22.1","children":[{"name":"TFR2","children":[{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4wascvqjaabaadq","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4yascvqjaabaaaq","size":1},{"name":"undefined","size":24},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4wascvqjaabaacq","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4yascvqjaabaaay","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4wascvqjaabaadm","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4wascvqjaabaacy","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4yascvqjaabaabi","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjz4yascvqjaabaaau","size":6}]}]}]},{"name":"9","children":[{"name":"q22.2","children":[{"name":"SECISBP2","children":[{"name":"undefined","size":30},{"name":"aaaacxi7gkabkascvqjaabaaea","size":9},{"name":"aaaacxi7gkabkascvqjaabaae4","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gkabkascvqjaabaaf4","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gkabkascvqjaabaaey","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gkabkascvqjaabaafq","size":10}]}]}]},{"name":"12","children":[{"name":"q15","children":[{"name":"NUP107","children":[{"name":"undefined","size":16},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaaby","size":10},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaade","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaadq","size":9},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaab4","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaacu","size":9},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaaem","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaaa4","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaace","size":8},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaaee","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaady","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaabq","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaaca","size":8},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaabi","size":10},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaabm","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaacy","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaada","size":10},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaac4","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaabu","size":9},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaacm","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaacq","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaadu","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaad4","size":1},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj74sascvqjaabaadi","size":4}]}]}]},{"name":"17","children":[{"name":"p13.1","children":[{"name":"SCO1","children":[{"name":"aaaacxi7gjwlyascvqjaabaacu","size":25},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjwlyascvqjaabaace","size":39}]}]}]},{"name":"19","children":[{"name":"q13.2","children":[{"name":"SPINT2","children":[{"name":"aaaacxi7gjuvmascvqjaabaadm","size":1},{"name":"undefined","size":5},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjuvmascvqjaabaadi","size":3},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjuvmascvqjaabaade","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjuvmascvqjaabaac4","size":6},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjuvmascvqjaabaada","size":4},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjuvmascvqjaabaadu","size":2},{"name":"aaaacxi7gjuvmascvqjaabaadq","size":1}]}]},{"name":"p13.12","children":[{"name":"PRKACA","children":[{"name":"aaaacxi7gkb32ascvqjaabaagi","size":9}]}]}]},{"name":"22","children":[{"name":"q13.33","children":[{"name":"SCO2","children":[{"name":"undefined","size":32},{"name":"aaaacxi7gka5qascvqjaabaaai","size":35},{"name":"aaaacxi7gka5oascvqjaabaacq","size":7},{"name":"aaaacxi7gka5qascvqjaabaaay","size":21},{"name":"aaaacxi7gj4eqascvqjaabaab4","size":115},{"name":"aaaacxi7gka5oascvqjaabaacm","size":5}]}]}]}]}


// vue configuration
var Main = {
    data () {
      return {
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.renderZoomableCircles()
    },
    methods: {
        renderZoomableCircles(){
          var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 20,
    diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 5])
    .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .padding(2);



  var root = d3.hierarchy(jsonData)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
       }

    },
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>


<div id="app">
 <svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
</div>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps.